# Fix decimal being retrieved from Database as string in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, string, decimal

If I have a column like this 'price' as decimal, when I get this value from Database, it returns a string instead of decimal or float. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think PHP has a built-in data type that can correctly correspond to a MySQL decimal type since floating point types in PHP are not precision types

Comment: You used `laravel` tag in question so I am assuming you're using Laravel. Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: Please provide the snippet of code where being a string causes trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this before showing;

```
$price = (float)$product->price;
```

Or you can make a function, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

in the migration make sure that the column is decimal

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->decimal('price');
    });
}
```

then cast it in the model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'price' => 'decimal:2',
];
```

now you can retrieve it in the controller or in the frontend

```
$price = Product->price; --> in the Controller

{{ $product->price }} --> in the view
```

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it in the whole project by casting in model

```
protected $casts = ['column_name' => 'type'];
```

example:

```
protected $casts = ['price' => 'float'];
```

documentation link:
[click here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators)